# Can You Determine the Azure Refresh Token Expiration Date

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

For a long time, you could routinely count on the expiration of an Azure refresh token to be 14 days from when it was last used, up to a maximum of 90 days after it was initially obtained.  There's been some work for a while now that the product group is starting to publicize a bit more about changing that to a longer value for a better user experience.  For details, see the blog here:  https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2017/08/31/changes-to-the-token-lifetime-defaults-in-azure-ad/ and preview documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes.

As a service provider that relies up on these tokens, it's important for us to know how long a token is actually valid for once it is handed to us.  I'm not currently seeing anything in the AuthenticationResult we get back using ADAL that provides any info about the maximum age for the refresh token.  Is there any way we can programmatically determine this?

Answer (score 1):

After Azure AD issues the access token & refresh token , you can find the lifetime of JWT token in claims . But From ADAL 3.X version , ADAL doesn't expose refresh token , it will automagically use it whenever you call AcquireToken and the requested token need renewing.

Refresh tokens expires in 14 days by default . You can create and set token lifetime policy using Azure AD Powershell Commands as shown in the document .

Comment: Thanks Nan. The expiration date in the claim is for the access token though, not the refresh token.  I'm aware of the policies that you can set to change the refresh token defaults (they are in the links I posted above); the problem I'm trying to solve is to those values when you don't know what policy is being used, because the token may be coming from a user that's not even in your tenant.

Comment: You doesn't need to care about the lifetime of the refresh token , just use the AcquireTokenSilentAsync function which will automagically use refresh token to renew the access token . When refresh token is expired ,redirect user to AAD login page again to do re-authentication  in catch exception area .

Comment: Actually we DO need to care about the lifetime of the refresh token, which is why I asked the question.  We perform a number of services outside the context of an interactive browser session, so we need to know when the token is getting close to expiring so we can ask the user to come back and refresh it.